# unable to use fromStdString in qt

Tags: qt

I am unable to use the function fromStdString.
it is said in the qt assistant that, "This operator is only available if Qt is configured with STL compatibility enabled.". but i don know how to enable this.
please provide the solution.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        std::string read;
        QString monthsArr[12];
        QStringList monthlist;
        std::ifstream readfile;
        readfile.open("/home/pcamdin/practice/qtcpp/qtprogs/qtcpp/months.txt");
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
            readfile >> read;
            monthsArr[i] = fromStdString(read);
            monthlist << monthsArr[i];
            qDebug() << i+1 << ": " << monthsArr[i];
        }

        qDebug() << "the first " << monthlist.size() << " months of the year are " << monthlist;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't u use QTextStream and QFile?

Comment: Either you have to recompile your Qt or use Qt classes instead of STL classes as already mentioned by @saeed

Comment: Thank you saeed and scai. I used QFile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STL support is compiled in by default (at least when you build it yourself).

Unless something has changed in 4.8 that I am unaware of, fromStdString is a static member of QString, so you should be calling it like

```
monthsArr[i] = QString::fromStdString(read);
```

Simply calling fromStdString in the global namespace does not compile under 4.7.3.

Answer (score 2):

Even if Qt was configured with -no-stl you can interact with std::string and containers, it only disables some syntactictic sugar. You can e.g. used QString::fromLatin1(some_std_string.c_str(), some_std_string.size()) or QString::fromUtf8(...) or fromLocal8bit(...) depending on the encoding of the data in the std::string. This is arguably favorable in any case as it makes the encoding concersion explicit.